# Saving Backbone JSON object to MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, backbone.js, decode

I'm saving Backbone model data, which POSTs a JSON object to my save.php file. As the model data will be for my application's users, I'd like to store unique values in a MySQL table.

Currently, I'm using this method:

```
$values = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$name = $values["name"];

$sql="INSERT INTO `users` (name) VALUES $name";
```

It's giving me this error

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'John Doe' at line 1
```

If I pass a simple string in the query, it works the way I'd like:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `users` (name) VALUES ('John Doe')";
```

My questions are:

- Why is $name not a string?
- Is this the best way to insert a JSON object into a MySQL table?

Thank you!

Comment: Always use prepared/parameterized queries!  You may be opening yourself to SQL injection attacks, and it's likely that your value for `$name` is the problem anyway.

Comment: can you please try print_r($values) and share?

Comment: print_r($values) yields:
Array ( [name] => John Doe )

Comment: I'm not sure how to use prepared/parameterized queries. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) is just a representation of your data : once decoded `$values["name"]` contains a string with your value, *John Doe*. This means that, as is, your request expands to

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `users` (name) VALUES John Doe";
```

which is both an invalid syntax and very insecure.

Use the [PDO class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) wherever you can, something like this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES(?)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(
    $name
));
```